# Angular $injector:modulerr Error after upgrading to angularjs v1.8.2

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-injector

I have a program that has been using jquery v1.9.1 and angularjs v1.4.7, and after upgrading them respectively to their latest versions (jquery v3.6.0 and angularjs v1.8.2) I've been solving all of the bugs except for this one.
[Injector Modulerr Error][1]

Which is identical to the error in Angularjs' website https://code.angularjs.org/1.8.2/docs/error/$injector/modulerr
I've updated all the files manually to their latest versions including ngRoute but it doesnt even hint where the problem is or what file is causing the issue. Any ideas?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmbQI.png